# Error response from daemon: make cli opts()

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I run `docker-compose up --build` and I receive this error:

```
 making volume mountpoint for volume /Users/alexrein/Documents/projects/cdm/tur: mkdir /Users: operation not permitted
```

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node:20

WORKDIR /app

CMD [ "yarn", "run", "start:prod" ]

VOLUME [ "app" ]

EXPOSE 3000
```

And the docker-compose file looks as follows:

```
version: '3.8'

networks:
  dual-localhost:
    driver: bridge
services:
  nepa_api:
    command: yarn start:dev
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./:/app

  db:
    image: mysql:8
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql.cnf:/etc/mysql.conf.d/mysql.cnf
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=paymentdb
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=qwerty1234
    networks:
      - dual-localhost

volumes:
  mysql:
```

Why is it trying to create /Users in the container? What is going on here?

The OS I am using is MacOS.

Comment: I wonder if the Dockerfile `VOLUME` directive is causing this problem.  You don't need that line (pretty much ever) and you can just delete it.  Since you're not installing code in the image and overriding the `command:` you could just run `image: node:20` with the same effect; and if you're doing that, it might be easier to `brew install node` and use that host Node without Docker.

Comment: @DavidMaze Got it. I tried removing the line and doing a rebuild, but the error remains...

Comment: @DavidMaze Though the error message has slightly changed: `Error response from daemon: make cli opts(): making volume mountpoint for volume /Users/alexrein/Documents/projects/cdm/tur/mysql.cnf: mkdir /Users: operation not permitted`

Comment: @DavidMaze I commented out that line with the config. And now we are back to the previous error.